# No schemas have been found - Spring Boot WS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have the next throuble: 
When I follow the [Spring boot WS example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/#initial) with maven, when I follow the steps, after add the xsd file, the guide indicate how to add the plugin to pom.xml file and this automatically turn the xsd file into java class objects. But I've received this:

```
No schemas have been found (org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc:xjc:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: No schemas have been found
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:376)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    ...
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.tester</groupId>
<artifactId>test-ws</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>test-ws</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is a screenshot how is look like the error:
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: outputDirectory should be ${project.build.directory}

Comment: thanks you, but that's not solved the error :(

Comment: is there any XSD in ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/?

Comment: yes sr. but the error hasn't gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if someone has the same error, I got the solution like this:

First, I configured the maven user settings in eclipse by adding a separate repository folder for the related project (Override the default path located in X:\Users\User.m2\repository).
I removed two custom profiles that I had in the previous file.
I updated the project and magically, the error disappeared.
Thanks to all for the help.